# Strapi: "created_by", "updated_by" fields to track changes on content

Tags: strapi

I was wondering if there is a way to include a record of the user / admin user who made a change to content via the admin panel or API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a topic about adding an history in Strapi

https://spectrum.chat/strapi/general/keep-track-of-content-changes~ddc22ab7-e306-4804-bfab-a90e0f42d537